# Can I specify private key in git config?

Tags: git, version-control

I want to use separate private key for a single git repository.

I don't have access to  home directory or I can't set env variables as well.

Is there any I can specify it in `.git/config`

Because then I can chnage the .git/config to use ssh instead of https.
Currently I have hardcoded user:pass in url of config file

Comment: I'm curious, how did this situation come about?

Comment: @Schwern The situation in in AWS i have git repo in snapshot with hardcoded username:pass in git config. This was working fine.around 20 diff people using that snapshot. During provisiong people do git pull and it worked. But now  i had to ssh for that na di don't have control over other people code. The only thing i have is snapshot which i can chnage

Comment: I figured it was something like that. Git is not a release system. Use it as one at your peril.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use authentication agent forwarding when logging into the remote machine to run git commands. [Here's a guide to setting that up](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/).

An authentication agent (usually `ssh-agent`) will store your keys in memory so you don't have to keep typing in the password. Authentication agent forwarding is when a remote machine is allowed to use your agent. When you `ssh` into a machine with forwarding, you can then `ssh` again from there as if you had all the keys of your local machine.

It's really handy and avoids the need to copy your private keys all over the place.